# How to get monthly report from two different month?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table named Leave it contains 2 rows

```
no=1 Leave=CL,Lnumber=2,FromDate='2015-01-10',ToDate=2015-01-11'
no=2 Leave=CL,Lnumber=2,FromDate='2015-01-12',ToDate=2015-01-13'
no=3 Leave=CL,Lnumber=2,FromDate='2015-01-15',ToDate='2015-02-16'
no=4 Leave=CL,Lnumber=2,FromDate='2015-01-31',ToDate='2015-02-01'
```

Here I want to get january month leave report(leave and Lnumer). How can I fetch this considering this FromDate and ToDate
The answer should be like this

```
Leave=CL,Lnumber=7 (for jan month)
Leave=Cl,Lnumber=1 (for feb month)
```

I am using MSSQL 2008. You can add extra fields if it is necessory. Thank You

Comment: why is Lnumber = 3 for January?

Comment: @Quannt,See the dates '2015-01-31 has one leave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend building a calendar table (basically a tally table, but with dates). Then join your leave table to the calendar table between the from and to dates, and count the days that fall in the interval.

```
;with t as
(
    select no=1, Leave='CL',Lnumber=2,FromDate=cast('2015-01-10' as date),ToDate=cast('2015-01-11' as date) union all
    select no=2, Leave='CL',Lnumber=2,FromDate=cast('2015-01-31' as date),ToDate=cast('2015-02-01' as date)
), cal as
(
    select top 10000 _date = cast(cast(row_number() over (order by (select null)) + 41000 as datetime) as date)
    from sys.objects a, sys.objects b
)
select 
    t.Leave,
    _year = datepart(year, c._date), 
    _month = datepart(month, c._date),
    count(_date)
from t
inner join cal c
    on c._date between t.FromDate and t.ToDate
group by t.Leave, datepart(year, c._date), datepart(month, c._date)
```

Comment: wow what a logic man..really appreciatable. If I have more than 2 data How can I do in this sameway??What I mean see my edited question..

Comment: Well see now I'm confused. I THOUGHT you wanted to count up the number of days in a given month which someone was on leave, but that would yield 17 days in February and given then updates to your source data, which leads me to believe I misunderstood what you're trying to do. Can you please clarify how it is you wind up with the result set you've outlined?